# Check radio button state in a Behat Mink scenario?

Tags: symfony, tdd, behat, gherkin, mink

I need to see in the output if a given radio button was checked. What kind of definition should I use? I've Googled about it a lot and didn't find a solution (which is probably right in front of me, as someone will probably assure me).

Comment: [Behat Cheat Sheet & Mink Cheat Sheet](http://blog.lepine.pro/images/2012-03-behat-cheat-sheet-en.pdf) has useful info for you.

Answer (score 5):

Mink provides a step for testing checkboxes :

```
the "form_checkbox" checkbox should be checked
```

But for radio buttons, you'd need to write your own step. Something like :

```
/**
 * @Then /^Radio button with id "([^"]*)" should be checked$/
 */
public function RadioButtonWithIdShouldBeChecked($sId)
{
    $elementByCss = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', 'input[type="radio"]:checked#'.$sId);
    if (!$elementByCss) {
        throw new Exception('Radio button with id ' . $sId.' is not checked');
    }
}
```

You can use the find() method to target an element using CSS selectors. Here, we search for a radio button that is checked and with a given id.

Answer (score 4):

This definition works for me:

```
And the "radio-buton-name" field should contain "radio-button-value"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it uses step definition shipped with Mink.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own step definition. For example this is what I did:

```
/**
 * @When /^I check the "([^"]*)" radio button$/
 */
 public function iCheckTheRadioButton($labelText)
     {
     foreach ($this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage()->findAll('css', 'label') as $label) {
         if ($labelText === $label->getText() && $label->has('css', 'input[type="radio"]')) {
             $this->getMainContext()->fillField($label->find('css', 'input[type="radio"]')->getAttribute('name'), $label->find('css', 'input[type="radio"]')->getAttribute('value'));
             return;
         }
     }
     throw new \Exception('Radio button not found');
 }
```

I know this is an old question but I didn't really find a good answer to it while searching on Stack Overflow and Google so I post my solution here. It might help somebody.

http://blog.richardknop.com/2013/04/select-a-radio-button-with-mink-behat/

Answer (score 0):

The method provided by the Behat/Mink extension itself works pretty well:

**@version** `Behat v3.0.14`

**@see** `\Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext`

```
/**
 * Checks checkbox with specified id|name|label|value.
 *
 * @When /^(?:|I )check "(?P<option>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function checkOption($option)
{
    $option = $this->fixStepArgument($option);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->checkField($option);
}
```

Just tested and it works fine also with labels (as mentioned in the phpdoc just above the method definition).

Comment: Please read the question carefully: it is not about how to set the state, it is about how to assert the state.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was worth mentioning, I added one for a checkbox that uses the label to find it.

```
/**
 * @Then the checkbox for :checkboxLabel should be selected
 */
public function theCheckboxForShouldBeSelected($checkboxLabel)
{
    $elementByCss = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', 'label:contains("'.$checkboxLabel.'") input:checked');
    if (!$elementByCss) {
        throw new Exception('Checkbox with label ' . $checkboxLabel.' is not checked');
    }
}
```